# How would you convert this If, Then Else recursions to pattern matching?

Tags: pattern-matching, ml

Working in ML I have a recursive function, written in if, then, else style.  The function has two base cases, Null List, and Null tail of list. The first base case is easy to convert to pattern matching style.

```
if(Null L) then false
```

becomes

```
fun oddNum(nil) = false
```

I am not sure how to write the other base case in pattern matching style.

```
else if (Null tl(L)) then true
```

I have tried this

```
| oddNum(nil(tl(L)) = true
```

My problem is that I do not know how to declare the list L as x::xs, before I write my second base case "| oddNum(nil(tl(L)) = true"

Answer (score 4):

```
fun oddNum nil = false
  | oddNum (_::nil) = true
  | oddNum (_::_::xs) = oddNum xs
```